# How to delete the default top and bottom bar?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I want to to delete the top and bottom bar so that my app really uses the full screen.
How do I do that?

[iphone simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LLOf.png)

Comment: There are no "bars" in your picture. Something is wrong with how you configured the view controller; the green _should_ occupy the whole screen. You need to tell us more about how the view controller and app are configured. It looks like the green thing is pinned to safe area; if so, that's your mistake right there. But that's just a guess; not info provided by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your green View constraints to be with respect to the Super View instead of the Safe Area, and the white areas will disappear.